# Is it possible to evaluate error of numeric schemes by using integrals?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-calculus

I'd just like to know if it is possible to evaluate the error of a numerical scheme by using it's solutions integral?

To elaborate this. I have long transmission line, which I evaluate over time numerically. I also have the exact solution on any point at any time. What I'd like to do is to plot the function of the starting (or end) point over time, as well as it's numerically simulated value over time. 
Approximating their integrals in MATLAB and subtracting them.

Is this value a valid measurement for the error or - when using multiple numerical schemes - a suitable validation which one is better for this case?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral of the raw error (or the *average* error) can be a poor measure, because if the error alternates in sign, the positive and negative contributions will cancel out.

Prefer the integral of the absolute error or the squared error.

Another measure can be useful (but does not involve an integral): the maximum absolute error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Surely this makes sense, but using the absolute error (absolute sum of the integrals) will result in a good measurement?

Comment: @WilliamD.: what do you call good ? And what do you call the "absolute sum of the integrals" ??

Comment: Sorry, I am just getting into the subject - I try again: What you suggest ist to take the integral of the absolute error. If I do so, will this result in a measure such that I can compare the "effectiveness" or the "accuracy" for lets say a lax-friedrichs scheme and a maccormack scheme? hope that made it clear

Comment: What do you call effectiveness ? By the way, these estimators have nothing to do with the particular schemes that you mention.